# Scheduling a task to run after a SQL SERVER 2012 executes a different set of scripts?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, scheduled-tasks

Im working on a project for a job I am interning for. I've had a few months of database design.  I am still learning all the techniques.

I am currently trying to schedule a console app to run every so often. But first, my DBA script(s) need to be processed by the DBA productions team. The scripts create some tables and performs a data dump.   After, the script(s) is ran, I would like the console app to run 10, 20, 30, 45 minutes after the scripts are executed. (Those are test intervals.) I am thinking that an event trigger is the way to go, but I am not sure?

Comment: Is the DBA script integral to the process or just necessary setup? Can your script after doing the data dump also schedule the test steps for you?